# ruby 1.9.2 p180 crashing under os x lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

I use RVM to manage my rubies, I just upgraded to Lion and everything seemed to be working fine except I noticed ruby 1.9.2 p180 keeps crashing.  I tried under both webbrick and thin and it made no difference.  My stack was working fine under 1.9.2 p180 using 10.6.8 but now it's crashing often.

I'm running Rails 3.0.7.  It seems to happen most when using the omniauth gem, which relies on ruby-openid which you can see at the top.  Tried updating to the most recent versions of the gems, didn't seem to matter.

Is there a more stable version of 1.9.2 I should be using?

Full stack trace:

```
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0084 p:---- s:0415 b:0415 l:000930 d:000930 CFUNC  :next
c:0083 p:---- s:0413 b:0413 l:000406 d:000412 IFUNC 
c:0082 p:---- s:0411 b:0411 l:000410 d:000410 CFUNC  :bytes
c:0081 p:---- s:0409 b:0409 l:000408 d:000408 CFUNC  :each
c:0080 p:---- s:0407 b:0407 l:000406 d:000406 CFUNC  :zip
c:0079 p:0105 s:0403 b:0403 l:000402 d:000402 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60
c:0078 p:0069 s:0396 b:0396 l:000395 d:000395 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:40
c:0077 p:0124 s:0387 b:0387 l:000386 d:000386 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:45
c:0076 p:0320 s:0379 b:0379 l:000378 d:000378 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:331
c:0075 p:0059 s:0368 b:0368 l:000367 d:000367 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:196
c:0074 p:0035 s:0359 b:0359 l:000358 d:000358 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:130
c:0073 p:0074 s:0352 b:0352 l:000351 d:000351 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:118
c:0072 p:0019 s:0348 b:0348 l:000347 d:000347 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:243
c:0071 p:0103 s:0340 b:0340 l:000339 d:000339 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:228
c:0070 p:0152 s:0333 b:0333 l:000332 d:000332 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:123
c:0069 p:0138 s:0319 b:0319 l:000318 d:000318 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:102
c:0068 p:0048 s:0310 b:0310 l:000309 d:000309 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-openid-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:68
c:0067 p:0020 s:0305 b:0305 l:000304 d:000304 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-openid-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:63
c:0066 p:0177 s:0302 b:0302 l:000301 d:000301 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:58
c:0065 p:0177 s:0298 b:0298 l:000297 d:000297 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:41
c:0064 p:0019 s:0294 b:0294 l:000293 d:000293 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30
c:0063 p:0241 s:0290 b:0290 l:000289 d:000289 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44
c:0062 p:0019 s:0286 b:0286 l:000285 d:000285 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30
c:0061 p:0017 s:0282 b:0282 l:000281 d:000281 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.6/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27
c:0060 p:0014 s:0275 b:0275 l:000266 d:000274 BLOCK  /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
c:0059 p:---- s:0273 b:0273 l:000272 d:000272 FINISH
c:0058 p:---- s:0271 b:0271 l:000270 d:000270 CFUNC  :catch
c:0057 p:0086 s:0267 b:0267 l:000266 d:000266 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
c:0056 p:0036 s:0262 b:0262 l:000261 d:000261 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.0/lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:18
c:0055 p:0015 s:0258 b:0258 l:000257 d:000257 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
c:0054 p:0093 s:0251 b:0251 l:000250 d:000250 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0053 p:0155 s:0244 b:0244 l:000243 d:000243 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
c:0052 p:0046 s:0238 b:0238 l:000237 d:000237 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0051 p:0054 s:0233 b:0233 l:000232 d:000232 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182
c:0050 p:0027 s:0226 b:0226 l:000225 d:000225 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149
c:0049 p:0015 s:0215 b:0215 l:000214 d:000214 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302
c:0048 p:0014 s:0207 b:0207 l:000a00 d:000206 BLOCK  /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32
c:0047 p:0019 s:0205 b:0205 l:000204 d:000204 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:2
c:0046 p:0051 s:0201 b:0201 l:000200 d:000200 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12
c:0045 p:0019 s:0197 b:0197 l:000a00 d:000a00 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31
c:0044 p:0015 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.
c:0043 p:0029 s:0189 b:0189 l:000f50 d:000188 BLOCK  /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46
c:0042 p:0155 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416
c:0041 p:0011 s:0177 b:0177 l:000f50 d:000f50 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44
c:0040 p:0015 s:0173 b:0173 l:000172 d:000172 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107
c:0039 p:0049 s:0163 b:0163 l:000162 d:000162 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
c:0038 p:0017 s:0159 b:0159 l:000158 d:000158 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
c:0037 p:0027 s:0151 b:0151 l:000150 d:000150 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
c:0036 p:0032 s:0147 b:0147 l:000146 d:000146 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0035 p:0052 s:0138 b:0138 l:000137 d:000137 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0034 p:0014 s:0134 b:0134 l:000128 d:000133 BLOCK  /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0033 p:0019 s:0132 b:0132 l:000131 d:000131 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10
c:0032 p:0054 s:0129 b:0129 l:000128 d:000128 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0031 p:0193 s:0124 b:0124 l:000123 d:000123 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30
c:0030 p:0015 s:0117 b:0117 l:000116 d:000116 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.6/lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12
c:0029 p:0032 s:0110 b:0110 l:000109 d:000109 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:168
c:0028 p:0021 s:0106 b:0106 l:000105 d:000105 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77
c:0027 p:---- s:0101 b:0101 l:000100 d:000100 FINISH
c:0026 p:0015 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0025 p:0015 s:0094 b:0094 l:000093 d:000093 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13
c:0024 p:0015 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15
c:0023 p:0020 s:0079 b:0079 l:000070 d:000078 BLOCK  /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:84
c:0022 p:---- s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 CFUNC  :catch
c:0020 p:0135 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82
c:0019 p:0088 s:0066 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:57
c:0018 p:0036 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:42
c:0017 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH
c:0016 p:---- s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 CFUNC  :run_machine
c:0015 p:0248 s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256
c:0014 p:0066 s:0045 b:0045 l:000bc0 d:000bc0 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61
c:0013 p:0143 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:159
c:0012 p:0117 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:14
c:0011 p:0269 s:0032 b:0032 l:0002c8 d:0002c8 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:217
c:0010 p:0200 s:0027 b:0027 l:0019c8 d:0019c8 METHOD /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65
c:0009 p:0063 s:0024 b:0024 l:000015 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0468 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    /Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:002198 d:001d78 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:002198 d:002198 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:14:in `run'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `pre_process'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `catch'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `block in pre_process'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.6/lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.0/lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.6/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:41:in `call!'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:58:in `request_call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-openid-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:63:in `request_phase'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/oa-openid-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:68:in `start'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:102:in `call'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:123:in `begin_authentication'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:228:in `begin'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:243:in `begin_without_discovery'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:118:in `get_association'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:130:in `negotiate_association'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:196:in `request_association'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:331:in `extract_association'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:45:in `extract_secret'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:40:in `xor_secret'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `strxor'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `zip'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `each'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `bytes'
/Users/holden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `next'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000108ce664e rb_vm_bugreport + 110
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000108bda4b3 report_bug + 259
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000108bda621 rb_bug + 161
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000108c7d0c2 sigbus + 18
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8afd3cfa _sigtramp + 26
5   ???                                 0x00007fc26154cdd0 0x0 + 140472833330640

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I installed rvm using Xcode 4.1 preview 5, I'm going to try reinstalling Xcode 4.1 with the most recent version and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yes there is already a new version of 1.9.2 - [Ruby 1.9.2-p290](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/07/15/ruby-1-9-2-p290-is-released/).

And secondly, have you tried to delete the gem and reinstall (and recompiling) it? You need [Xcode 4.1](http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) to compile gems under Lion.

Comment: Well, it's a clean install.  I did not upgrade, and yes I have Xcode installed.  Thanks for the p290 tip, I'm going to see how that fairs.

Comment: Nope, still crashes under p290, installed all gems from sratch, same error.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have no current project using ruby-openid. Installing it works fine, but I can't get any further in testing.

Comment: @holden, when you say you have Xcode installed, did you download the latest version from the App Store and install it from your application directory?

Comment: @beerlington, yes, I "installed" it from the App store which puts it into Applications, then I installed the installer.  After which it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in Ruby, and 1.9.2-p290 doesn't fix it. A workaround is to patch the ruby-openid gem as described here:

[ruby-openid pull request #22](https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid/pull/22)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I uninstalled XCode 4.1 Preview 5 and then downloaded the final from the App store and it worked.  I'm not sure why, but using the same p290 version of 1.9.2 and compiled using the final Xcode 4.1 seemed to fix it.

I updated RVM and removed all the previous rubies, reinstalled all my gems and it works!

Answer (score 0):

For those of you whom are still facing issues with this the solution is to simply install Ruby 1.9.3. If you're using RVM with OSX lion then the installation of 1.9.3 may not work by default so try this:

> rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang